# Changing force throughout an animation

Tags: force-fields

Is it possible to change the strength of a magnetic force throughout an animation? I would like to increase the strength from -2 to 0 and then to 2. If you can help that would be great!

Comment: Add keyframes to the properties you want to change. Move your mouse over the first value, press the "i" key to create a keyframe, then move to a different frame and repeat the same procedure to create more keyframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Strength* of Force Fields can be keyframed, like the value of most properties in Blender.

To set a keyframe, go to the frame where you want to assign a *Force* value and set the value. Then, with your mouse over that field, press <kbd>I</kbd>. Now you can move to another frame, change the value and repeat.

Comment: I realized that cegaton also has answered your question but in the comments section. I'm not sure if that is intended or not and if, by giving an answer that is basically his comment, I have violated the site's etiquette. If cegaton would like to convert his comment into an answer, I'll remove this one.

Comment: No problem, it happens all the time. We posted at the same time and I didn't bother to make it an answer. Please keep on posting and helping to make this site useful for others : )